# How can I fix this alsamixer library error/ file not found?

Tags: archlinux, alsa

When I try to open alsa mixer the following error occurs:

*ALSA lib dlmisc.c:337:(snd_dlobj_cache_get0) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_ctl_asym.so (/usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_asym.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
cannot open mixer: No such device or address*

I tried reinstalling alsa-lib. But the error won't go away. **I use arch btw.**

**I have following packages in my system:
alsabat
alsa-info.sh
alsamixer
alsaucm
alsabat-test.sh
alsamixergui
alsactl
alsaloop
alsatplg  **

I also tried manually installing alsa-lib by:

1. wget ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/lib/alsa-lib-1.2.6.tar.bz2
2. tar -xvf alsa-lib-1.2.6.tar.bz2 && cd alsa-lib-1.2.6
3. ./configure && make && sudo make install
4. sudo ldconfig

But it wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but you could first try reinstalling those alsa packages you listed. With yay I sometimes had to do a rebuild when encountering similar error (correct library missing) using  `yay -S --rebuild package-name`.